# Telerik:RadRotator Not displaying(rendering) in IE9

Tags: telerik, rad

Ok i have a telerik:RadRotator on my page that loads a few images from the db, the rotator displays correctly in both FireFox and Chrome but when i open it in IE9 the rotator div is placed on the page but the rotator itself doesn't display(render).

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" runat="server" Width="791px" Height="215px"
ItemHeight="215px" ItemWidth="791px" OnItemDataBound="RadRotator1_ItemDataBound"
RotatorType="AutomaticAdvance" FrameDuration="10000" ScrollDuration="3000" CssClass="ImageRotator"
ScrollDirection="Right" PauseOnMouseOver="false">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypImage" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="imgScroller" runat="server" Width="791" Height="215" /></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Any ideas as to what is happening here? I have tried to remove the styles applied and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after much fuss I found that the scroller itself was wrapped in a hyperlink. After removing the hyperlink everything works 100%

Answer (score 0):

Such problems are often related to an incorrectly formatted HTML that is not ignored by IE, especially older versions of the browser. The only issue that I found in your code was the unclosed RadRotator control tag, although most probably you have missed it by accident. Since the code from your sample appears to be valid, it is possible that an erroneous content is inserted from the data source. Please verify that the content in the datasource is entered correctly and that the data, populating the items of the rotator, is properly escaped before it is used. You can also check if the RadRotator's items are rendered properly by examining the content of the **li** elements in the HTML representation of the control on the source of your page.

Comment: Hi I have taken a look at the html side of the rotator in the browser and the items are rendering correctly. The closing tag is there i just missed it when copying the code. When i switch IE9 into compatibility mode the rotater displays correctly.